# Merge PDF pages to 1 file without generating single page files

Tags: python, pdf, merge, pypdf

The goal is to take a set of jpg/tif images and convert them into 1 text-searchable PDF. I am using Python's PyPDF2 and pytesseract to accomplish this; however, I am unable to find a method of combining these pages without saving each page as its own PDF. Turns out some of these sets could be 1k-10k pages so saving each page individually is unfortunately no longer feasible ... here's what I've got so far:

```
# Convert each image to a searchable PDF
for fileset in filesets:
    merger = PdfFileMerger()
    page_path = fr".\output\pages"
    for file in fileset:
        # Load image, read with pytesseract
        path = os.path.join(download_location,file)
        img = cv2.imread(path,1)
        result = (pytesseract.image_to_pdf_or_hocr(img, lang="eng",config=tessdata_dir_config))
        # Save result as PDF
        f = open(os.path.join(path_out,getfilename.findall(file)[0])+".pdf","w+b")
        f.write(bytearray(result))
        f.close()
```

Which works just fine for single pages, and from here I could merge each of these pages and save them as one document such as:

```
# pdfs is a list of all the single page pdf's
for page in pdfs: 
    merger.append(page)

merger.write(fr".\output\{FILE}.pdf")
merger.close();
del merger
    
# Get rid of single page files
for page in pdfs: 
    os.remove(page)
```

This produces the text searchable PDF's as desired, but those individual page files are going to destroy my memory. I've tried appending the `result` object(s) to `merger`, which produces the `AttributeError: 'bytearray' object has no attribute 'seek'` error. I've also tried to read the `result` objects as PDF's with `PyPDF2.PdfFileReader()` and got a similar result. Any ideas?

Comment: PS: Because I have these PDF objects already in memory as byte()'s, I image it might be possible to combine them somehow directly, similar to adding a \n to a text file to create a new line, but my attempts at finding a way to do this has been futile as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO):

```
for fileset in filesets:
    merger = PdfFileMerger()
    page_path = fr".\output\pages"
    for file in fileset:
        # Load image, read with pytesseract
        path = os.path.join(download_location,file)
        img = cv2.imread(path,1)
        result = pytesseract.image_to_pdf_or_hocr(img, lang="eng",config=tessdata_dir_config)
        merger.append(BytesIO(result))

merger.write(fr".\output\{FILE}.pdf")
```